# How to make create and update use the same route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route and form that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @address, url: {action: "update_contact", controller: "checkouts"}, html: {class: ""} do |f| %>
```

My route looks like:

```
post "checkouts/:cart_token/update_contact" => "checkouts#update_contact", as: "checkouts_update_contact"
```

For updates the form is looking for a `PATCH` which I haven't defined, and so I get an error when the @address model already exists i.e. updates

How can I make my form always POST no matter what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `method: :post`

```
<%= form_for @address, 
    url: {action: "update_contact", controller: "checkouts"}, 
    html: {class: ""}, 
    method: :post do |f| %>
```

Without that Rails adds a hidden field which is used to fake a `PATCH` request when the form is used to update an object.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
```